# How to access the section title before the section is started?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

While designing the layout for a magazine I tried to have some section mark in the outer margin of the page. As every section starts on an own double page, but sometimes on the left and sometimes on the right, I want those marks to appear equally on both pages (one double page = one mark).

To illustrate the problem:

[image: illustration]

In this picture you see two sections. I would like to have "Preface" at the same position also at the image page and for the second section "Something" also at the section page.

The whole point of it: **How do I get the section title before I have started the section?**

If it helps, I use LuaLaTeX, so a Lua solution would be okay too.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,DIV=calc,BCOR=5mm,twoside,titlepage]{scrartcl}

%% packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

%% do the layout stuff
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{marginnote}

%% pagestyles
\newtcolorbox{markbox}[1][]{rotate=90,text width=4cm,halign=center,beamer,#1}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
\newlength{\twocentimetre}
\deftriplepagestyle{mypage}[0pt][0pt]%
    {}{}{}%
    {
        \ifthispageodd{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\headmark}{}}{}{
                \marginnote{
                    \setlength{\twocentimetre}{2cm}
                    \multiply\twocentimetre by \value{section}
                    \vspace*{\dimexpr-5cm-\twocentimetre}\begin{markbox}
                        \headmark\vspace*{.5cm}
                    \end{markbox}
                }
            }
        }{}
    }{Title here}{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{mypage}

%% KOMA customization
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{section}{\dothesection}
\newtcolorbox{sectionbox}{sharp corners=north,height=2cm,valign=bottom,halign=center,spread upwards}
\def\dothesection#1{
    \clearpage\begin{sectionbox}\huge #1\end{sectionbox}
}

%% own environments/commands
\NewDocumentEnvironment{picpage}{}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{mypage}}{\clearpage}
\NewDocumentCommand{\startsection}{s m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\section*{#2}}{\section{#2}}
    \markboth{#2}{#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\startsubsection}{s m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\subsection*{#2}}{\subsection{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \setcounter{page}{-1}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[spread sidewards=-1cm]
            \Huge\sffamily\bfseries Some title\\[.5em]
            \Large Some subtitle
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{titlepage}
    \begin{picpage}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \end{picpage}
    \startsection*{Table of contents}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]
        \makeatletter
        \@starttoc{toc}
        \makeatother
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vfill
    \begin{picpage}
        \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \end{picpage}
    \startsection{Preface}
        Quack
    \startsection{Something}
        Test
    \begin{picpage}
        \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \end{picpage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    Back
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* As advised by David Carlisle I turned my code into section-starting environments to enable those picture pages. Now there are some other problems:

- I now have to environments for starting a section (left/right), each with a "starred" version. I really dislike this approach, because it is in my view not very comfortable and provides no real logical structure.
- The y-shift of the left-sided image pages is wrong. That's of course logical, since the section counter has not been incremented at that point.

Is there a solution that's not that tedious?

New code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,DIV=calc,BCOR=5mm,twoside,titlepage]{scrartcl}

%% packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

%% do the layout stuff
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{marginnote}

%% pagestyles
\newtcolorbox{markbox}[1][]{rotate=90,text width=4cm,halign=center,beamer,#1}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1cm}
\newlength{\twocentimetre}
\deftriplepagestyle{mypage}[0pt][0pt]%
    {}{}{}%
    {
%       \ifthispageodd{
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\headmark}{}}{}{
                \marginnote{
                    \setlength{\twocentimetre}{2cm}
                    \multiply\twocentimetre by \value{section}
                    \vspace*{\dimexpr-5cm-\twocentimetre}\begin{markbox}
                        \headmark\vspace*{.5cm}
                    \end{markbox}
                }
            }
%       }{}
    }{Title here}{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{mypage}

%% KOMA customization
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{section}{\dothesection}
\newtcolorbox{sectionbox}{sharp corners=north,height=2cm,valign=bottom,halign=center,spread upwards}
\def\dothesection#1{
    \clearpage\begin{sectionbox}\huge #1\end{sectionbox}
}

%% own environments/commands
\NewDocumentEnvironment{picpage}{}{\clearpage\thispagestyle{mypage}}{\clearpage}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{startleftsection}{s m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\section*{#2}}{\section{#2}}
    \markboth{#2}{#2}
    \begin{picpage}
}{
    \end{picpage}
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{startrightsection}{s m}{
    \markboth{#2}{#2}
    \begin{picpage}
}{
    \end{picpage}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\section*{#2}}{\section{#2}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\startsubsection}{s m}{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\subsection*{#2}}{\subsection{#2}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \setcounter{page}{-1}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[spread sidewards=-1cm]
            \Huge\sffamily\bfseries Some title\\[.5em]
            \Large Some subtitle
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{titlepage}
    \begin{startrightsection}*{Table of contents}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \end{startrightsection}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white]
        \makeatletter
        \@starttoc{toc}
        \makeatother
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \vfill
    \begin{startrightsection}{Preface}
        \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \end{startrightsection}
        Quack
    \begin{startleftsection}{Something}
        \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \end{startleftsection}
        Quack
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    Back
\end{document}
```

Comment: is the previous page always an image associated to the following section (in which case you could code it as if the section started at the image, but with a delayed section head) or is it just standing in here for arbitrary content at the end of the previous section?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well it is everytime something connected with the new section.

Comment: oh well it's easy then just apply the sectionmark code at that point, basically that's where the section "really" starts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So you mean I should just put a `picpage` inside my `\startsection`? That's not very flexible in terms of the picture.

Comment: why not? it seems to me that the high level view is that you have a section heading that has a page break and a full page picture which is added to the left or right page by some logic about which I'm uncertain. so the markup could be `\mysection{section name}{image-filename}` and the code could start the `\cleardoublepage` specify the `\sectionmark` then add the image and heading or heading and image depending on (something?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, not really. I'd like to have the flexibility for more pictures, not only one. That's why an own environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you could extend the optional key-value syntax of the optional argument of `\chapter` (or `\section`). The side marks could be placed using `scrlayer` or `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,DIV=calc,BCOR=5mm,twoside,%
  headings=optiontotocandhead,open=left]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep}}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{markbox}[1][]{rotate=90,text width=4cm,halign=center,beamer,#1}
\newtcolorbox{sectionbox}{sharp
  corners=north,height=2cm,valign=bottom,halign=center,spread upwards*}
\FamilyBoolKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{titleleft}{@titleleft}
\@titlelefttrue
\DefineFamilyKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{imagecode}{%
  \long\def\chapter@imagecode{#1}%
  \FamilyKeyStateProcessed
}
\newcounter{abschapter}
\newlength{\chaptermarkoffset}
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  % calculate new vertical position of the marks
  \stepcounter{abschapter}%
  \global\chaptermarkoffset\dimexpr 2cm*\value{abschapter}+5cm\relax
  % restart vertical position of the marks, if lowest position has been reached
  \ifdim\chaptermarkoffset>\dimexpr \paperheight-4cm\relax
    \setcounter{abschapter}{1}%
    \global\chaptermarkoffset\dimexpr 2cm*\value{abschapter}+5cm\relax
  \fi
  \if@titleleft
    \typeout{TRACE: Title left \thechapter}%
    \ifx\chapter@imagecode\@empty\else
      \afterpage{%
        \thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
        \chapter@imagecode\clearpage\global\let\chapter@imagecode\@empty%
      }%
    \fi
  \else
    \typeout{TRACE: Title right \thechapter}%
    \chapter@imagecode
    \cleardoubleoddpage
    \thispagestyle{plain.scrheadings}%
    \global\let\chapter@imagecode\@empty
  \fi
  \begin{sectionbox}
    \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
  \end{sectionbox}
  \global\@titlelefttrue
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{}
\newcommand*{\chapter@imagecode}{}
\deftocheading{toc}{%
  \def\chapter@imagecode{\includegraphics{example-image}}
  \@titleleftfalse
  \@mkdouble{#1}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
}

\DeclareNewLayer[background,oddpage,rightmargin,
  contents={\hspace*{\fill}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \depth-\chaptermarkoffset\relax}{%
     \begin{markbox}\rightmark\end{markbox}}}
]{oddmarginnote}
\DeclareNewLayer[background,evenpage,leftmargin,
  contents={%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \depth-\chaptermarkoffset\relax}{%
     \begin{markbox}[rotate=180]\rightmark\end{markbox}}}
]{evenmarginnote}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{oddmarginnote,evenmarginnote}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{tcolorbox}[spread sidewards=-1cm]
  \Huge\sffamily\bfseries Some title\\[.5em]
  \Large Some subtitle
\end{tcolorbox}
\vfill

\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\chapter[titleleft=true,imagecode={\includegraphics{example-image-a}},head={title
  left}]{Testchapter with title left}
\Blindtext[10]

\chapter[titleleft=false,imagecode={\includegraphics{example-image-b}},head={title
  right}]{Testchapter with title right}
\Blindtext[10]

\chapter[titleleft=true,imagecode={\includegraphics{example-image-c}}]{Left
  manual break}
This is the text for the left page.
\clearpage

\Blindtext[10]

\chapter[titleleft=false,imagecode={\includegraphics{example-image}}]{First more}

\chapter[titleleft=false,imagecode={\includegraphics{example-image}}]{Second more}

\addchap[titleleft=false,imagecode={\includegraphics{example-image}},tocentry={}]{Not
numbered no ToC entry}

\end{document}
```

The Table of Contents demonstrates a not numbered chapter with image left:

[image: Table of Contents (image left, text right)]

Chapter 2 demonstrates a numbered chapter with text left (with automatic page break to the next left page):

[image: Chapter 2 (image right, text left)]

Chapter 3 demonstrates a numbered chapter with image left and text right:

[image: Chapter 3 (text left, image right)]

But Chapters without image are also supported:

[image: Chapter 1 (text left, no image]

And what about chapters without number? The most simple solution would be to use `\addchap` instead of `\chapter*`. To avoid an entry to the ToC simply use option `tocentry={}`. And what happens, if you have to much chapters so that the side mark would move outside the page? This cannot happen. `abschapter` will automatically reset to 1 and the marks will start again at the topmost position:

[image: Chapter without number but very late]

You could additional code for this situation, e.g., to change the color of the side marks or to throw a warning.

In the example, I've extended page style `plain.scrheadings` by a new layer. As an alternative you could define a new layer page style only for the chapter title pages. You can also extend page style `scrheadings` if you want. And you can still use `\ihead` etc. to configure the page head and foot of `plain.scrheadings` and `scrheadings`.

Comment: Great answer. Just one question: How do I pass the options to a `\chapter*`?

Comment: @TeXnician: See the heading of the ToC. You can set the macro and the switch by hand or make a new command `\schapter` or simply use `\addchap` (with `tocentry={}` it wouldn't make a ToC entry).

Comment: I really like your solution, but adding some content to a title-left chapter I encountered that there is a page break before the image (text continues). But there should be an image. Is that a new question or is there an easy fix?

Comment: @TeXnician: Do not understand your problem. I've shown a title-left chapter (second image). The text starts on the left page and automatically breaks to the next left page while the image is set to the right page.

Comment: Right, but I had added some five sections after the `\chapter` and every time as `\section{Test} A ` which caused that strange behaviour. As this is no real use case it's not a problem.